# Get Name of selected RadioButton in EXT-GWT RadioGroup

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I have following code:

```
final Radio trDelRadio = new Radio();
trDelRadio.setName("TDRADIO");
trDelRadio.setBoxLabel("Training");

final Radio cdcRadio = new Radio();
cdcRadio.setName("CDCRADIO");
cdcRadio.setBoxLabel("Content");

final Radio msRadio = new Radio();
msRadio.setName("MSRADIO");
msRadio.setBoxLabel("Management");

final Radio osRadio = new Radio();
osRadio.setName("OSRADIO");
osRadio.setBoxLabel("Outsourcing");


final RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup();
radioGroup.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
radioGroup.add(trDelRadio);
radioGroup.add(cdcRadio);
radioGroup.add(msRadio);
radioGroup.add(osRadio);
radioGroup.addListener(Events.Change, new Listener<BaseEvent>(){
       public void handleEvent(BaseEvent be) {
              GWT.log("Service type: " + radioGroup.getValue().getBoxLabel(), null);
        }
});
```

In this code I'm using GXT 2.0.1 create four radio buttons and then combining them into the radio button group.

Line

```
GWT.log("Service type: " + radioGroup.getValue().getBoxLabel(), null);
```

is retrieving Label of selected check box and works fine, but when I'm trying to get name or any other information it's  getting value of the RadioGroup. What am I doing wrong here? How do I get selected radio button in RadioGroup?

Answer (score 0):

I use `radio.setValueAttribute(String value)` method to store value.

Answer (score 0):

I think, that's you need.

```
radioGroup.addListener(Events.Change, new Listener<FieldEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(FieldEvent fe) {
        GWT.log(fe.getField().getName() + " : " + fe.getValue());
    }
});
```